# css rotation with absolute position

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I have a fixed background, and a div with an absolute position in it; I would like to place it at the `top: 5px and left: 5px`, It's working when I have no rotation of the text, but I want to get my text verticaly, so I make a rotation 90°. I would like to stick it from `left: 5px and top 5px` but when I apply the rotation, the text is cut above the page, and even the left part is misplaced ..

Here is some **css code** (I'm using glamor but it should work the same as normal css)

```
const background = css({
  background: 'url(/static/profile.jpg) no-repeat left top fixed',
  backgroundSize: 'auto 100%',
  backgroundColor: '#040404',
  position: 'fixed',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100vh',
  top: '0',
  left: '0',
  zIndex: '0',
})

const socialBloc = css({
  color: '#fff',
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '5px',
  left: '5px',
  zIndex: '999',
  '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(270deg)',
  '-moz-transform': 'rotate(270deg)',
  '-ms-transform': 'rotate(270deg)',
  '-o-transform': 'rotate(270deg)',
  transform: 'rotate(270deg)',
})
```

And the **Html**:

```
<PageLayout pageName="Index">
  <div className={socialBloc}>
     <Link prefetch href='*'><a className={a} target="_blank">Link</a</Link>
     <Link prefetch href='*'><a className={a} target="_blank">Link</a</Link>
  </div>
  <div className={background}>
  </div>
</PageLayout>
```

It's working great with horizontal (no rotation) but when I apply the rotation my text is over..

Thanks for help

Comment: Post the rendered HTML and CSS please so that we have an [mcve]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have made your socialBloc an inline block so that it's length is limited.

Next, I translate it to the left to make the rightmost corner be where the left one was, and rotate it around the left top center:

```css
.socialBloc {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 36px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="socialBloc">
  <a href="#link">Link</a>
  <a href="#link">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's work perfectly, I think it's cause I hadn't add the translateX, I tried transform-origin but didn't work first ;) Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
transform: rotate(270deg);
```

you can use:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
```

The latter is explicitly intended for manipulating the display of text.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.socialBloc {
font-size: 36px;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialBloc">
<a href="#link">Link</a>
<a href="#link">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like this way is much better then my! Will remember.

Answer (score 0):

Without a visual example to go by I can only guess your issue, but perhaps [using `transform-origin` would help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin). This will allow you to define a point on the element other than the centre for the `transform` to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have not close your `<a>` tags and if problem is not with it, seems like you need to work with `transform-origin`.

Here is a working fiddle to help a bit:
https://jsfiddle.net/huLxsv0f/3/

I know it's not perfect solution. But I'm not sure you'll find better one...